# Finding nth Occurrence in multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two columns with team names and two columns with corresponding stats.  I need to go through the 2 columns and find the stats that match the team name, and they need to be in order.  VLOOKUP, MATCH, and SEARCH don't seem to work with multiple columns.  Does anyone know how this can be done?[image]

Comment: Does this need to be dynamic to allow for more data? Or will there always only be 2 values for each team?

Comment: It needs to be dynamic

Comment: Given that information, would it be possible for you to amend your example to make things clearer? At the moment, you have each team appearing precisely twice each.

Comment: so you want to dynamically populate the `X - Home` and `X-Vis` columns?

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to populate the 4 columns on the right. So column 'A' would list each time it finds Team A and the corresponding stat 'X'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in your picture, the "Home" title is in cell `B2` then the following array formula can be put in the cells `H3:L7` (array formulas need to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($D$1,-1+SMALL(IF(($B$3:$B$7=H$2)+($C$3:$C$7=H$2),ROW($B$3:$B$7),"X"),ROW()-ROW($2:$2)),--NOT((INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF(($B$3:$B$7=H$2)+($C$3:$C$7=H$2),ROW($B$3:$B$7),"X"),ROW()-ROW($2:$2)))=H$2))),"")
```

Let me break it down...

- the logic is: `OFFSET(top_of_results,row_number_that_has_Nth_team_score,0_or_1_for_home_or_away)`
- this is wrapped in an `IFERROR` in for where there isn't e.g. a 5th score for team A
- using the array part `IF(($B$3:$B$7=H$2)+($C$3:$C$7=H$2),ROW($B$3:$B$7),"X"` we get an array of that has the `ROW` number if either (done using `+`) `B` or `C` have a value matching our team header (`H$2`) or an `X` otherwise
- using `SMALL(...,ROW()-ROW($2:$2))` we get the Nth smallest row, based on 1st being in row 3, 2nd in row 4 etc.
- to get whether it is home or away, we check column B on our row to see if it matches `--NOT((INDEX($B:$B,row_number_that_has_Nth_team_score-O)=H$2))` this gives 0 for home, 1 for away and this is used to offset the column

Hopefully it makes sense. Array formulas are very powerful, if a little confusing :-) I recommend [CPearson's intro](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx) for more information.

Good luck!

Comment: @adam12344 Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!